# Laravel JSON response object attributes are all strings except id

Tags: json, laravel, response

I downgrade laravel app 10 to 8,but now my laravel object JSON response attributes are all strings except id, you can see an example:

```
{
    "res": {
        "id": 5,
        "user_id": "3",
        "shipping_method": "standard",
        "order_date": "2023/07/06",
        "total_amount": "16980",
        "status": "validation",
        "paid": "0",
        "created_at": "2023-07-06T22:32:31.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-07-06T22:32:32.000000Z",
        "rating": "0",
        "items": [...]
    }
}
```

`paid` and `total_amount` are for example respectively boolean and integer, you can see my migration:

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('shipping_method');
            $table->date('order_date');
            $table->decimal('total_amount', 10, 2);
            $table->string('status');
            $table->boolean('paid');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

and also the code to get orders is:

```
public function index($userId)
    {
        $orders = Order::where('user_id', '=',  $userId )->get();
        foreach ($orders as $o){
            $items=$o->items;
            foreach ($items as $i){
                $productId=$i->product_id;
                $product=Product::find($productId);
                $i->product=$product;

            }
        }
        return $orders;
    }
```

Please help can the object returned as migration expected.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but you should really take advantage of "eager loading" so you don't have all those queries to get each product separately. Your entire function body should be able to be replaced with this: `return Order::with('items.product')->where('user_id', $userId )->get();`.

Comment: Why did you downgrade Laravel?

Comment: I want to post on a server, but it doesn't support php 8

Answer (score 0):

Add the $casts property to your Order model and specify the attribute types.

```
protected $casts = [
    'paid' => 'boolean',
    'total_amount' => 'decimal:2',
];
```